# LLL algorithm in NTL library

Tags: c, ntl

I am learning to use the NTL library currently, especially for the LLL algorithm later. Does anyone have any idea of the usage of the LLL function in the NTL library? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need anything beyond the documentation at e.g. http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/LLL.txt

Comment: @mc110: I saw this documentation. But how do you use the LLL function, i.e. can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the "documentation":

```
long 
[G_]LLL_{FP,QP,XD,RR} (mat_ZZ& B, [ mat_ZZ& U, ] double delta = 0.99, 
                   long deep = 0, LLLCheckFct check = 0, long verbose = 0);
```

You can use the LLL function by calling e.g.

```
LLL_FP(B)
```

The suffix `FP` marks the precision, since the calculations are done in floating point arithmetic. This is done for speedup the LLL algorithm. If you need better prezision, you can choose one of the other suffixes `QP`, `XD` or `RR`.

Notice that `B` has to be a matrix of type `ZZ`. NTL uses the **rows** of the matrix as basis of the lattice. (I ran into this problem, due to Prof. C.P. Schnorr writes a lattice basis as **columns**)

After thereduction the LLL-reduced basis overrides your input matrix `B`. If you need the transition matrix `U`, that do the reducktioin `U*B = B_LLL`, you can call

```
LLL_FP(B, U)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can the matrix B be non-square?

Comment: I think yes, but maybe it has to be a basis, that means it has to have mor columns than rows. but you can easily test this.